# Non-sensical return pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to go through a list of objs and find the obj with the "Title" field equal to objTitle

```
function objFinder(objTitle, event, objs) {
can.each(objs, function(obj, key) {
    if (obj["Title"].trim() == objTitle.trim()) {
        console.log(obj)
        console.log(objTitle + " found")
         return obj;
    }
})
}
```

I have gone through in the debugger in chrome and seen that it does hit the return statement and the obj in the return statement is the correct one. The problem is when I do  console.log of this function it shows as undefined and when I evaluate the statement in console it returns undefined. Why is this?

can.each() is just a package implementation of a foreach loop

Comment: Your return statement returns execution from the anonymous function, not from the objFinder function.

Comment: I understand that **can** is a package implementation for beverages ... but not for each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the callback return false when you find the right object:

```
function objFinder(objTitle, event, objs) {
var result = null;
can.each(objs, function(obj, key) {
    if (obj["Title"].trim() == objTitle.trim()) {
        console.log(obj)
        console.log(objTitle + " found")
         result = obj;
         return false;
    }
})

return result;
}
```

Comment: This of course assumes that `.each()` allows `return false` to break the loop (common, but not guaranteed: `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't even allow for it).

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement is for its `function` parent, which is ***not*** `objFinder`.

```
function objFinder(objTitle, event, objs) {
    can.each(objs, function(obj, key) {
//                 ^^^^^^^^
        if (obj["Title"].trim() == objTitle.trim()) {
            console.log(obj)
            console.log(objTitle + " found")
            return obj;
//          ^^^^^^
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I return for objFinder? sorry I am new to javascript. Not used to nested functions yet

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot, it depends on what implementation of `each` you're using. If `return false` can break out of the `each` loop, then you can use an intermediate variable to store the object to return. Otherwise you'll need to do a bit of checking for the rest of the loop, or use a vanilla JS `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad states, your return just jumps out of the anonymous function given to each().

To solve this, you could do something like this:

```
function objFinder(objTitle, event, objs) {
  //Btw. where do you define "can"?
  var retObj = undefined;

  can.each(objs, function(obj, key) {
      if (obj["Title"].trim() == objTitle.trim()) {
          console.log(obj)
          console.log(objTitle + " found")
          retObj = obj;
          return;
      }
  });

  return retObj;
}
```

Cheers,
Florian